# Headphone on PCM5102a: separate amp?

Tags: amplifier, dac, esp32, headphones

My goal is to connect my headphones to either a Bluetooth music audio source via ESP32 and a local source (radio / walkie talkie). I want to use this on my motorcycle for listening to music and navigation from my smartphone (via BT), being automatically interrupted by the radio. I'm not shooting for perfect sound quality, but decent.

I have a good idea on how to connect the radio to the headphones and switch the source using a multiplexer ([74LVC1G3157](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC1G3157.pdf) to be exact). However, I am unsure on how to output to the headphones from the ESP32 reliably and safely.

I connected a [PCM5102a](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/pcm5102a) as a higher quality alternative to the internal DAC and I also have a [PAM8403](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/PAM8403-247318.pdf) board available.

I am not sure whether to connect my headphones to the PCM5102 directly or to add an amp in between.

I already read that the PCM5102 is designed for line level with 1 kΩ impedance minimum, but also that some users are driving their headphones directly off them. In tests, my 8 Ω headphones worked fine plugged into the PCM5102 line level jack.

As stated above, I have a PAM8403 board, but the power seems way to large for headphones, and first tests show the sound is harsh, way to loud, and distorted at lower volume settings (reducing the volume via Bluetooth settings, not changing anything on the PAM, so lower input into the amp).

The PAM-board has two 100 kΩ SMD resistors soldered onto it, which according to my research should be setting the amplification. 100kΩ seems to be within spec and I am not at all competent enough to switch SMD components.

I understood that driving a low-impedance load would probably result in low power (OK for headphones) and risk high currents (so add a small cooling fin?). But I am a novice in everything electrical and HF especially.

I also have not yet selected the headphones to actually drive (eyeing the Sena HD speakers), but I am expecting low-impedance (4-16 Ω).

So, would you recommend to

- connect the headphones to the PCM5102A directly, since this should work reliably (maybe with small modifications such as added capacitors or resistors)
- add the PAM8403 inbetween (or another amp, if so, please give me advice on available recommended alternatives)
- do something completely different?

My research (googling) resulted in conflicting and unclear results, maybe because I just don't know the right words to describe my problem.

Comment: You can get DAC chips with integrated headphone amplifier and variable attenuation for volume control. For a Bluetooth device I'd consider one of those rather than building each component separately.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of such a chip? I found a few RasPi-Shields that cover many things, but they get quite expensive (50+€ vs 15€ for the components I have now).
Anything available in Germany/EU would be great. Till now AliExpress was the only source I found multiple boards possibly solving my issues. But since I have no experience to judge them based on specs, I don't fancy the long lead time with shipping from Asia.

Comment: Oh one thing to add: Since I need at least 3 modules (the ESP32 for logic, the DAC and the switch for the radio), I have no issue with adding another one. So it really does come down to cost for me: Is a DAC with build-in amp cheaper than a standalone amp? Than fine. Otherwise, no point for me to replace the PCM5102.

Comment: You can buy an integrated Bluetooth receiver for a few dollars online so building this from individual one off parts is going to be a lot more expensive regardless. You can buy audio codecs and amplifiers from normal suppliers like digikey.

Comment: I get the feeling you greatly overestimate my competence in this area. Looking for audio codecs on digikey I found a bunch of PCM DIP-chips, but I understand these are just alternatives to the PCM5102. What I could not find was a fully integrated board with the features you mentioned. I found something like this on amazon (a DollaTek board), but with 12€ this was more expensive than I suspect a headphone amp chip would be.
However, Digikey does provide a few headphone amp chips. I will research which values to look for. If someone knows what to use in this specific case feel free to post them

Answer (score 0):

The PCM5102A is not rated to drive headphones directly. In theory we don't know what loads it can drive and will it suffer from long term reliability issues if it drives phones directly, or is it just that for loads below 1 kohm, you should not expect anything out of the rated 112 dB SNR and -93 dB THD for example, it may just be just as poor as some other DAC you already have.

On the other hand, you will be using headphones riding a motorbike so you can't expect to hear Hi-Fi quality anyway.

The PAM8403 will only have 80 dB SNR and 90dB dynamic range so it will make signal quality worse anyway after PCM5102A, but it can still be better than required while driving.

If PAM8403 is too loud, just add volume control. Although if anything goes wrong in your circuit, the PAM8403 can suddenly start producing scary noise, and it can provide it at extremely high volume right at your ears, as the chip still has gain even if volume control before it is turned low.

You can also drive phones directly through 1kohm resistor to increase resistance, but output might be too low.

An op-amp might be better for driving the load than PAM module with huge gain. Of course you can attenuate the PAM output too to limit the maximum volume.

Adjusting the volume on your Bluetooth module mau do it digitally so it may be the reason why at low volume it sounds distorted. Adjust the volume by attenuating it externally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I feel it covers quite a lot.
You are right on audio quality, I will be driving ~35€ headphones after all. The SNR, THD and dynamic range you mentioned don't really mean anything to me, but a short google seach gives me the feeling the PAM values should be ok for my goals

I get from your reply that there is no reliable data on wether the PCM5102 will run into issues with driving headphones long term, right?

Can you give me a hint on how to correctly control the volume?

And if I'd switch to an op-amp, what are the right specs to look out for?